# java program after compilation shows me this error:

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String [] args)
     {
        int a,b,c;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        a=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        b=sc.nextInt();
        c=add(a,b);
        System.out.println("Sum is"+c);
     }
     public static int add(int x,int y)
     {
         int sum;
         sum=x+y;
         return sum;
     }
}
```

Error:

```
Error:HelloWorld.java:13: error: no suitable method found for println(String,int)
        System.out.println("Sum is",+c);
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/nEDRPt, it is working fine

Comment: @AtulKumar Take a closer look at the error.

Answer (score 1):

From this:

```
Error:HelloWorld.java:13: error: no suitable method found for println(String,int)
        System.out.println("Sum is",+c);
```

You seem to be calling **`System.out`** including a comma separator when invoking println() on it (this may be a typo). As the method `println(String,int)` is undefined, you get the error:

```
System.out.println("Sum is",+c); //2 arguments. Note that this would also increment c
```

**Delete the comma and use the String's** `add` operator (`+`) to append the `int`'s value as Sring to the resulting text:

```
System.out.println("Sum is " + c); //1 argument
```

Comment: @Noobcoder97, take a look at this, as it may be just a typo mistake

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to  use " , " as value separator in this case

System.out.println("Sum is" +c);